# DevExpress XtraCharts - Create horizontal bar chart

Tags: devexpress

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 XtraReports package 1.0 and MVC DX11.2 Report Controls
I am working on producing various Bar Charts. I need to produce a horizontal bar chart and can see that there is a solution for DevExpress.XtraCharts.v12.1 but it uses XYDiagram.Rotated Property.

(see http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsXYDiagram_Rotatedtopic)

This is not available for me in DX11.2

Can anyone suggest how horizontal bar charts be created either using the chart designer or in code?

Many thanks
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DX 11.2 also have same property.** Check the following code snippet of DX 11.2 demos

```
if (settings.Diagram is XYDiagram) {
        ((XYDiagram)settings.Diagram).Rotated = options.Rotated;
        Axis2D axisY = ((XYDiagram)settings.Diagram).AxisY;
        axisY.Interlaced = true;
        axisY.Title.Text = "Population, millions";
        axisY.Title.Visible = true;
    }
    else {
        XYDiagram3D diagram = (XYDiagram3D)settings.Diagram;
        diagram.AxisX.Label.MaxWidth = 60;
        diagram.AxisY.Interlaced = true;
        diagram.RotationType = RotationType.UseAngles;
        diagram.RotationOrder = RotationOrder.XYZ;
        diagram.ZoomPercent = 140;
        diagram.VerticalScrollPercent = 4;
    }

    Html.DevExpress().Chart(settings)
    .Bind(Model)
    .Render();
```

[image]

> Check your DevExpress Demos folder for Chart
>   Demo(C:\Users\Public\Documents\DevExpress 2011.2
>   Demos\Components\ASP.NET\MVC\CS\MVCDemos\Views\Chart), there you will
>   get the partial view file name "BarViewsSideBySideStackedPartial"
>   which help to implement this.

Hope this help.